# It only runs the first " if " why so?

Tags: c

it only prints " Sunday " even if I typed another date in. how do I resolve this?
i usually don't use int main() but a friend of mine did this method and it worked but I'm using a program that is written by the school so I can't paste it directly. but I'm pretty sure I copied it corectly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int date;

int main()

{

    printf(" \n\n              JUNE 2020           \n");
    printf(" SUN   MON   TUE   WED   THU   FRI   SAT \n");
    printf("        1     2     3     4     5     6  \n");
    printf("  7     8     9    10    11     12    13 \n"); 
    printf(" 14    15    16    17    18     19    20 \n");
    printf(" 21    22    23    24    25     26    27 \n");
    printf(" 28    29    30 \n\n\n");

    printf("Here is your schedule for June 2020         \n");
    printf("Please select a date: ");

    scanf("%d", &date);


    if (( date == 7 ) || ( date == 14 ) || ( date == 21 ) || ( date || 28 ))

    {
        printf("sunday! ");
    }

    else if (( date == 1 ) || ( date == 8 ) || ( date == 15 ) || ( date == 22 ) || ( date == 29 ))
    {
        printf("monday! ");
    }

    else if (( date == 2 ) || ( date == 9 ) || ( date == 16 ) || ( date == 23 ) || ( date == 30 ))
    {
        printf("tuesday! " );
    }

    else if (( date == 3 ) || ( date == 10 ) || ( date == 17 ) || ( date = 24 ))
    {
        printf("wednesday!");
    }

    else if (( date == 4 ) || ( date == 11 ) || ( date == 18 ) || ( date == 25 ))
    {
        printf("thursday!");
    }

    else if (( date == 5 ) || ( date == 12 ) || ( date == 19 ) || ( date == 26 ))
    {
        printf("friday!");
    }

    else if (( date == 6 ) || ( date == 13 ) || ( date == 20 ) || ( date == 27 ))
    {
        printf("saturday!");
    }

    return 0;



} // end
```

Comment: `date || 28` doesn't look right

Comment: It looks like the question has been edited to hide the bug.  Don't do that.  It makes the entire post useless to anyone else.

Comment: Why did you edit the question? How would anyone be able to see what was the issue? That's a no-go.Questions at SO shouls be useful for all readers, not only to the person asking them.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem

```
( date || 28 ))
```

Is always true and hence first `if` is always true.

Change to

```
( date == 28 ))
```

Explanation

```
( date || 28 ))
```

Is equivalent to `if (date || true)` and it's always true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you have probably made a typo in the line:

```c
if (( date == 7 ) || ( date == 14 ) || ( date == 21 ) || ( date || 28 ))
```

The condition is always evaluated as true because of `( date || 28 )`.

Change it to `( date == 28 )` and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the last condition of your first if statement.

```
if (( date == 7 ) || ( date == 14 ) || ( date == 21 ) || ( date || 28 ))
```

should be changed to:

```
if (( date == 7 ) || ( date == 14 ) || ( date == 21 ) || ( date == 28 ))
```

Previously, it was evaluating `( date || 28 )`, which is true as `date` is a positive integer. This made the entire condition true.

Answer (score 1):

In your first if statement, you have `(date || 28)` which should have been `(date == 28)` instead:

```
if (( date == 7 ) || ( date == 14 ) || ( date == 21 ) || ( date || 28 ))

    {
        printf("sunday! ");
    }
```

The reason that it always runs only the first `if` statement is that `else if` only gets checked if the above `if` statement is not true. In your case, the first if statement is always true, because `( date || 28 )` expression is always true.